# SQL query that can identify distinct values and maximum values

Tags: mysql, sql, select, distinct, max

I need an sql statement to select distinct records and at the same time compare maximum or rather latest date from database.This is my table fleetschedule.It contains fleetschedule id,companyid,route,fleetnumber,traveldate. SQL query I tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT fleetnumber and max(traveldate), routeid, companyid, traveldate
FROM fleetSchedule
```

problem is it gives just 1 value(the maximum).
I require all distinct buses(identified by fleetnumbers) that travelled on the maximum/latest date.
sample data of outcome i'm looking for:

```
fleetnumber routeid companyid   traveldate
MSH-17E     RT17    MSH         2009-07-26
FDH-17D     RT17    FDH         2009-07-26
MSH-17F     RT17    MSH         2009-07-25
MSH-27E     RT27    MSH         2009-08-24
```

sample of table am using:

```
fleetScheduleID companyID    routeID     travelDate fleetNumber
20                  MSH      RT17        2009-07-26     MSH-17E     
19                  MSH      RT17        2009-07-26     MSH-17D 
18                  MSH      RT27        2009-08-24     MSH-27E
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT fleetNumber, 
       MAX(travelDate) AS travelDate, 
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(routeID ORDER BY travelDate DESC), ',', 1) AS routeID, 
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(companyID ORDER BY travelDate DESC), ',', 1) AS companyID
FROM fleetSchedule
GROUP BY fleetNumber;
```

Comment: what if I want to limit the schedule to the end of this year how can I do so?

Comment: @user2083526 Just add `WHERE travelDate < '2014-01-01'` before `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select * 
from fleetSchedule
where travelDate = ( select max(travelDate) from fleetSchedule )
```

Comment: Peter that seems like a better improvement but it gives me only 1 of the fleets the maximum 1.maybe after my editing of the question you can see what i mean.

Answer (score 0):

```
select fleetnumber, routeid, companyid, max(traveldate)
from fleetSchedule
group by fleetnumber, routeid, companyid
```

To be clear, the above would give you each distinct bus and the latest date it traveled. If you would rather a list of distinct buses that have traveled on the latest date across the whole table, use the following

```
select distinct fleetnumber, routeid, companyid
from fleetSchedule
where traveldate = (select max(traveldate) from fleetSchedule)
```

Comment: the 1st seems to get the values I require but they look different from the 1s Mikhail's above got me.let me compare and see which works best.the 2nd gives a single value.thanx